# Contact form not sending mail

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

I have this contact form and the PHP for it but it wont send the emails at all, can i get a second set of eyes on this please? the first code sample below is from the index.html and PHP is from contact.php

Contact form:

```
<form action="contact.php" method="POST">
    <p>Name</p> <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
    <p>Email</p> <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control">
    <p>Phone</p> <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control">

    <p>Request Phone Call:</p>
    Yes:<input type="checkbox" value="Yes" name="call" class="form-control">
    No:<input type="checkbox" value="No" name="call" class="form-control">
    <p>Priority</p>
    <select name="priority" size="1" class="form-control">
        <option value="Low" class="form-control">Low</option>
        <option value="Normal" class="form-control">Normal</option>
        <option value="High" class="form-control">High</option>
        <option value="Emergency" class="form-control">Emergency</option>
    </select>

    <p>Message</p><textarea name="message" rows="6" cols="25" class="form-control"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send"class="form-control"><input type="reset" value="Clear" class="form-control">
```

Contact.php-

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$call = $_POST['call'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$priority = $_POST['priority'];
$type = $_POST['type'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Phone: $phone \n Call Back: $call \n Priority: $priority \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "test@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

Comment: Can you please tell what the error is?

Comment: $recipient = "test@gmail.com"; // here this email ID exists or not?

Comment: Are you really sending the email to test@gmail.com?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP mail form doesn't complete sending e-mail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644436/php-mail-form-doesnt-complete-sending-e-mail)

Comment: there is no error, i get the thank you page but the email never actually goes, oh and test@gmail.com is changed on the live version

Comment: I hope you not testing this using your own localhost

Comment: No, this is up on a live site at the moment so there should be no reason for it not to work, that i can see anyway

Comment: Do you have access to EXIM server logs? Probably GMail denies the mail because of spam

Comment: You cannot set from email address as you like. It has to be in the same domain as hosted domain.

Answer (score 0):

mail(to,subject,message,headers,parameters);

But in case of your code to email id is fixed : test@gmail.com
change $recipient with $email.